# Could not access the wordpress login and lost the email details too

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cpanel

Could not access the wordpress login and lost the email details too, so how to fix it by accessing mysql database table

Comment: Why can't you access the login page? Do you have a GUI for your database, something like phpmyadmin?

Comment: it say, username and password is error (access denied)

Comment: Okay. So what you've said is false. The login page is the page with the login form (which one you CAN access). You CAN'T login. Thats a big difference. And please answer my second question.

Comment: @twinfriends. hi thanks for your reply and comments, i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to database then follow these steps

1. Choose the database of WordPress installation which password need to recover.
   if you don’t remember database name then go file directory of WordPress install and look for `define('DB_NAME', 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME');` in wp-config.php file
2. Once clicked on `users` table a list of users will show.Click on `Edit` link of the user whose password you want to reset.
3. In `user_pass`  column select `md5` in drowdown.
4. Enter the password of your choice in corresponding value field.
5. Click on `Go`  to save the settings.

You should be able to Login with your new password

Comment: if it is you can verify this answer so other people can also know its working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, if I get it, you want to reset your password but you doesn't event know the e-mail. You should:

1. Connect to your database and check the table `wp_users`.
2. Find the user your want to *reset*.

[image: User row]

3. Create a new password for this user using a [WP Password Generator](http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4).
4. Update the row on your database with the new hashed password.
5. Login.